# как открыть файлы в папке для того, чтобы в дальнейшем можно было считывать нужные данные в фале (файлы формата .doc) на python

Tags: python

```
Indecator_For_List = 0
List_Of_Document_Download = os.listdir('C:/Users/linur/OneDrive/Рабочий стол/Дипломная работа/Data/Download/')    

def Collecting_Documents():
            for i in range(len(List_Of_Document_Download)):
                while Indecator_For_List <= i:
                    First_Documents = open(List_Of_Document_Download[Indecator_For_List], 'rb').readlines()
```

Comment: Непонятна суть вопроса. Чем не устраивает имеющийся код, какие с ним проблемы?

Comment: а название переменной "индЕкатор" у вас от слова "индеец"?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36001482/read-doc-file-with-python

Answer (score 0):

Вы можете перечислить все файлы в текущем каталоге с помощью  `os.listdir` и читать файлы по очереди.

```
import os
for filename in os.listdir(os.getcwd()):
   with open(os.path.join(os.getcwd(), filename), 'r') as f:
```

дальше свое дело

или

```
with os.open(path. "r") as files:
  #дальше делаете свое дело
# как сделаете, он закроется
```